# Package with pre-made set of customizable drawings

Tags: ctan, tikzlibrary

I remember a LaTeX package I found time ago, which provided a lot of good quality drawings to use in presentations. Things like avatars, object of some kinds, etc.. The drawings were customizable and composable with a lot of gadgets, as for example choosing which hat each avatar wears etc.

Maybe it was a tikz library instead of a simple package.

Which was the name of this package? Does it exist anymore?

Comment: maybe https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzpeople?lang=en ?

Comment: Yes! That was it. Unfortunately I remembered incorrectly. I thought it was a generic collection of drawings but instead it's focused on people. Is there any similar library of ready drawings, like a generic clip art archive of tikz pictures?

Comment: @samcarter would you like to write an short answer?

Comment: @Bobyandbob Thanks for your ping. I think it would be better to close it as duplicate of the clipart question. The answers there already mention tikzpeople and many other useful resources.